# Creating histograms of distance from the origin for 2D Random Walkers

Tags: matlab, histogram, matlab-figure, random-walk

Let's say you can show the distribution in space of the the positions of a large number of random walkers at three different time points. This was provided an answer to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52379612/creating-graphs-that-show-the-distribution-in-space-of-a-large-number-of-2d-rand) and with some tweaks is beautiful.

```
clc;
close all;
M = 1000; % The amount of random walks.
steps = [100,200,300]; % here we analyse the step 10,200 and 1000
cc = hsv(length(steps)); % manage the color of the plot
%generation of each random walk
x = sign(randn(max(steps),M));
y = sign(randn(max(steps),M));
xs = cumsum(x);
xval = xs(steps,:);
ys = cumsum(y);
yval = ys(steps,:);

hold on
for n=1:length(steps)
    plot(xval(n,:),yval(n,:),'o','markersize',1,'color',cc(n,:),'MarkerFaceColor',cc(n,:));
end

legend('100','200','300')
axis square
grid on;
```

Now to the question, could I in some way use the `hist()` and `subplot()` functions to show the distance from the origin of the random walkers at three separate time points, or more I guess, but three for simplicity.

I'm not sure how to go about this beyond producing distributions of random walkers at the three time points themselves so far.

Comment: Can you provide an example of which kind of plot your want, I do not understand how you want to visualize the distance. By the way after answering your previous question yesterday, I asked myself if there was a way to generate  the `xval` and `yval` values without using brute force and indeed it's possible: check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52389357/how-to-generate-a-number-representing-the-sum-of-a-discrete-uniform-distribution)

Comment: To be more specific, my aim is to try and show the spread of all walkers distance from the origin using a histogram, so I can eventually compare it to the normal distribution of 2D random walkers by overlaying it on top to either confirm or deny that large amounts of walkers at seperate time points are behaving as expected. Thank you for your link I will check it out now.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that I've understand your question, I think that you want to use the `bar` plot with the stack option.

I've used the answer of @LuisMendo to my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52389357/how-to-generate-a-number-representing-the-sum-of-a-discrete-uniform-distribution) to increase the code efficiency.

```
steps = [10,200,1000]; % the steps
M     = 5000; % Number of random walk
DV    = [-1 1]; % Discrete value
p     = .5; % probability of DV(2)
% Using the @LuisMendo binomial solution:
for ii = 1:length(steps)
    xval(ii,:) = (DV(2)-DV(1))*binornd(steps(ii), p, M, 1)+DV(1)*steps(ii);
    yval(ii,:) = (DV(2)-DV(1))*binornd(steps(ii), p, M, 1)+DV(1)*steps(ii);
end
[x, cen] = hist(sqrt(xval.^2+yval.^2).'); %where `sqrt(xval.^2+yval.^2)` is the euclidian distance
bar(cen,x,'stacked');
legend('10','200','1000')
axis square
grid on;
```

Increase the # of bins in the histogram function to increase the plot precision.

**Results:**

[image]